# Optimizing Android Code

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my application I am drawing 12 markers to the map and then for each of these markers I have 12 dilalog boxs that pop and show the address of the location of the marker. I was thinking there must be a better way of doing this, So I have been trying to create a list to hold all the markers and pass the marker from the list into the dialog box when it is tapped, so I do not have to have 12 seprerate dialog boxes.

At the moment my markes are being drawn to the screen but the dialog does not show when the marker is taped it does however show when I use 12 seperate dialog boxes. can anyone point me in the right direction of where the problem may lie.

```
 private List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();


//sets the default map location to glasgow
double defaultLat = 55.85432829452839;
double defaultLng = -4.268357989501965;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_muc_main);             

    //get drawable IDs
    icoUser = R.drawable.yellow_point;          
    icoScotstoun = R.drawable.squash; 
    icoIbrox = R.drawable.rugby;
    icoSecc = R.drawable.boxing;
    icoKelvingrove = R.drawable.bowls;
    icoHockey = R.drawable.hockey;
    icoVeledrome = R.drawable.athetics; 
    icoCeltic = R.drawable.party;        
    icoTollcross = R.drawable.aqua;         
    icoHampden = R.drawable.athetics;        
    icoCathkin = R.drawable.cycleing;
    icoStrathclyde  = R.drawable.tri;    
    icoEdinburgh  = R.drawable.athetics;     
    icoDundee = R.drawable.shooting;        


    //ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MucMainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, paths);
    ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MucMainActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_layout, maptypes);
    mapTypeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    mapTypeSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);       
    mapTypeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);       

    //checks if the map has been instantiated or not if it hasn't then the map gets istantiated
    if(mMap == null)
    {
        //passes the map fragment ID from the layout XML and casts it to a map fragment object
        //and gets the google map object.
        mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    }

    if(mMap != null)
    {
        defaultSetting();           
        addListenerOnChkIos();
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    }


    //showUserLocation();          

}


//@Override
// public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
//{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.muc_main, menu);
    //return true;
//}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int position = mapTypeSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    switch(position)
    {
    case 0:
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        break;

    case 1:
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        break;

    case 2:
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        break;

    }
}


@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void showUserLocation()
{
    //get location manager
            locMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            //get last location
            Location lastLoc = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            double lat = lastLoc.getLatitude();
            double lng = lastLoc.getLongitude();
            //create LatLng
            LatLng lastLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

            //remove any existing marker
            if(marUser!=null) marUser.remove();
            //create and set marker properties
            marUser = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(lastLatLng)
            .title("You are here")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(icoUser)));
            //move to location
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(lastLatLng), 1000, null);      

}   

public void defaultSetting()
{

    //sets the map type
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    // sets the default location of the map to Glasgow
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(defaultLat, defaultLng), 12.0f), null );
    //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(55.85432829452839, -4.268357989501965)), 3000, null);     
    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(defaultLat,defaultLng)).title("hello"));
    addMarkers();


}

public void addMarkers()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 11; i++) 
    {
        red = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(55.88069,-4.34025)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(icoScotstoun)));
        markers.add(red);
        blue = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(55.85360,-4.30454)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(icoIbrox)));
        markers.add(blue);
        green = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(55.86070,-4.28761)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(icoSecc)));
        markers.add(green);
        yellow = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(55.86782,-4.28875)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(icoKelvingrove)));
        markers.add(yellow);
        brown = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(55.84496,-4.23671)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(icoHockey)));
        markers.add(brown);
        pink = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(55.84496,-4.23671)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(icoVeledrome)));
        markers.add(pink);
        purple = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(55.84959,-4.20555)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(icoCeltic)));
        markers.add(purple);
        orange = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(55.84505,-4.17607)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(icoTollcross)));
        markers.add(orange);
        cyan = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(55.82570,-4.25239)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(icoHampden)));
        markers.add(cyan);
        magenta = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(55.79550,-4.22329)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(icoCathkin)));
        markers.add(magenta);
        olive = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(55.78529,-4.01481)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(icoStrathclyde)));
        markers.add(olive);
        darkBlue = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(55.93920,-3.17273)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(icoEdinburgh)));
        markers.add(darkBlue);          
        LightGreen = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(56.49302,-2.74663)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(icoDundee)));
        markers.add(LightGreen);
        //dundeeM = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(56.49302,-2.74663)).title("DUNDEE"));
    }
    markers.size(); }


@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) 
{   
    if(marker.equals(marker.getId()))
    {
        // Create custom dialog object
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MucMainActivity.this);
        // Include dialog.xml file
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
        // Set dialog title
        dialog.setTitle(marker.getTitle());

        // set values for custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textDialog);
        text.setText("Cathkin Braes Country Park" + "\n"+ "cathkin Road" + "\n" + "Glasgow" + "\n" + "G45");
        ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageDialog);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.biking);

        dialog.show();

        Button declineButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.declineButton);
        // if decline button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        declineButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // Close dialog
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });         
    }


    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the method

```
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker)
```

you have a condition check:

```
if(marker.equals(marker.getId()))
```

try removing it. You store markers in the private member defined at the beginning

```
private List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
```

so I don't see why you should check a marker to be equal to the marker id.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed that was the problem,removing the condition check solved this. Thanks Junior

Updated go is as follows

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) 
{           

    {
        // Create custom dialog object
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MucMainActivity.this);
        // Include dialog.xml file
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
        // Set dialog title
        dialog.setTitle(marker.getTitle());

        // set values for custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textDialog);
        text.setText(marker.getSnippet());
        ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageDialog);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.biking);

        dialog.show();

        Button declineButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.declineButton);
        // if decline button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        declineButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // Close dialog
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });         
    }       

    return true;
}
```